# How to set the boundary of a multipart request using TRestRequest?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to use the Delphi's Rest components and I'm stuck while uploading a stream. On Indy components for instance I need to add MultiPartFormDataStream and on the Request Content Type I need to set boundary. But, I can't reproduce it on the TRESTClient and TRESTRequest.
Here is the code:

```
//Fields
    rCliTest: TRESTClient;
    rReqTest: TRESTRequest;
    rRespTest: TRESTResponse;

procedure TForm46.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StreamContent: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StreamContent := TMemoryStream.Create;
  img1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(StreamContent);

  rCliTest.BaseURL := 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/33/uploadImage';
  rCliTest.ContentType := 'application/json';

  rReqTest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  rReqTest.AddParameter('additionalMetadata', 'Tets');
  rReqTest.AddBody(StreamContent, ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

  rReqTest.Execute;

  Caption := rRespTest.Content;
end;
```

When I try to execute I get this error:

> {code":400,"type":"unknown","message":"org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException:
>   Missing start boundary"}

This is the curls used as base to implement the code:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json'
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer 3d9979829200e7cc7e6e6ac039f75e01' -F additionalMetadata=rodrigo
    'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/33/uploadImage'
```

---

**Updates**:

1. Currently I'm using Delphi Seattle, but previously I was using
   Delphi X5 and in Delphi X5 is not possible to send stream like I
   want.
2. I tried to create the same scenario using [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) and Advanced Rest Client (ARC, it's a google chrome extension). On PostMan I could make it work but on ARC I couldn't. To check what was sent to my RestApi I use [Fiddler from Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4), that's a kind of wireshark but for RestClients. 
   There are the information that I got from Fiddler from the:

   PostMan Request (that worked):

[image]

If I use the Delphi code like this, I get the error 415:

[image]

But If I change the request format to multipart_form_data, I get this error and this output:

> 400
>   {"code":400,"type":"unknown","message":"org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException:
>   Missing start boundary"}

[image]

Comment: Indy's `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` generates a random boundary. `TIdHTTP.Post()` retrieves that boundary and puts it in the `Content-Type` header for you.

Comment: `rCliTest.ContentType := 'application/json';` is wrong. It should be `'multipart/form-data'`. You are not sending a JSON post.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`TRESTRequestParameterKind`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind) documentation:

> pkREQUESTBODY: The parameter value will be used as a request body. **If more than one parameter of this kind exists, the request will use a multi-part body**.

Try something more like this instead:

```
procedure TForm46.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  StreamContent: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StreamContent := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    img1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(StreamContent);
    StreamContent.Position:= 0;

    rCliTest.BaseURL := 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/33/uploadImage';    
    rCliTest.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';

    rReqTest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    rReqTest.AddParameter('additionalMetadata', 'Test',
      TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);    
    rReqTest.Params.AddItem('file', StreamContent,
      TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY,
      [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode],
      TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    rReqTest.Execute;

    Caption := rRespTest.Content;
  finally
    StreamContent.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think that it's a version issue. I'm using Delphi XE5 and I don't have the "AddItem" with there parameters. I have this: 
function AddItem: TRESTRequestParameter; overload;
function AddItem(const AName, AValue: string; AKind: TRESTRequestParameterKind; AOptions: TRESTRequestParameterOptions = []): TRESTRequestParameter;
function AddItem(const AName, AValue: string): TRESTRequestParameter; 
function AddItem(const AName, AValue: string; const AKind: TRESTRequestParameterKind; const AOptions: TRESTRequestParameterOptions; AContentType: TRESTContentType): TRESTRequestParameter;

Comment: "*I'm using Delphi XE5*" - That is important information that should have been included in your question. The `TBytes` and `TStream` overloads were added in 10.0 Seattle. In XE5, you likely won't be able to send a `multipart/form-data` post that includes a file.

Comment: Now I'm testing on Delphi Seattle.
Using this code I get the error 415, unsupported media type.

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino What does the actual HTTP request look like? Worse case, you could just abandon `TRESTClient` and go back to `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: I really would like to use your components Remy, these defaults .......

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino: are you experiencing a particular problem that prevents you from using `TIdHTTP`?

Comment: @RodrigoFariasRezino: that info does not answer my question. I have no idea how to make this work correctly in `TRESTClient`, or if it even can work (I don't use Embarcadero's REST framework, mainly because it is too complicated and doesn't always work as advertised), but have tried `TIdHTTP` yet? This situation is a no-brainer for its `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` class using its `AddFormField()` and `AddFile()` methods.

Comment: The only thing that the TRestClient are used all over the places. It was the standard since they started the project. So preferably we would continue using it.  And yes, I already did a test and this problem is solvable using the indy's components, so this doubt it's just about of TRestClient, on Indy it's working nicely!

Comment: From [RESTRequest How to send a multipartformdata in a HTTP Post body?](https://community.embarcadero.com/answers/restrequest-how-to-send-a-multipartformdata-in-a-http-post-body) on the Embarcadero community forum, the REST framework simply doesn't handle `multipart/form-data` correctly, or at least not consistently across platforms  You are best off using another REST client, if not Indy.